# Customazing Bootstrap layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in bootstrap. I'm trying to create an index html page of online shop.
Here is an example - https://jsfiddle.net/a393wtng/1/
If you resize output frame you will see that 4 products can be placed in each 'row'

I want to add margin

```
margin-left:7px;
margin-right:7px;
```

to each product (lines 24, 25) in css file. But in that case I'll get a 3 products in each 'row'.
I tried to make an image a bit smaller to get product width a bit less, however I 've got unexpected result: the same product width and left align of internal elements - http://screencast.com/t/TU9yl3dK5se

So, I have 3 questions:

1. How to add margin-left and right to the product and leave 4 products
   at each 'rows'?
2. How to avoid "padding-left" when image size has been
       changed?
3. I will be very appreciative for any recommendations for
   that html/css/bootsrap code

Comment: You can't use `col-`s just inside `col-`.  Every 4 `col-sm-3` should be wrapped into `row`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to center the image? Use 'margin: 0 auto;' on the img selector.

Comment: it's not good to merge classes `product` and `col-sm-3`. the right way is to define: `<div class="col-sm-3"> <div class="product...">...</div></dv>`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of points to note here:

1. I see from the source code on your JSFiddle frame, that you're using the **bootstrap v4** CSS files. I'm not sure whether *v4* handles spacing exactly like *v3* does, as a lot has been rewritten for v4. My feedback is based on experience with v3.
2. With bootstrap it's better to create custom CSS that changes the **padding** rather than the **margin** - especially for *left* and *right* (top and bottom are usually okay).
3. As @Banzay has said; it's better to add a new `<div>` with class **product** within the **col-sm-3** `div`.
4. You'll notice that once you've separated the divs in point 3, the **col-*** divs have padding already set (*which updates based on whether they're the first, middle or last divs within a row*).
5. Then all you need to do is set the *top* and *bottom* padding to space them out vertically. The best is to pad the ***top*** of the **col-md-10** `div` and the ***bottom*** of each of the **product** `divs`. You'll notice though, that the **product** CSS class now doesn't do anything special.

I've updated your JSFiddle HTML and CSS as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-10 border padding-top">
    <div class="col-sm-3 padding-bottom">
        <div class="product grey-border round-border">
            <img class="img-thumbnail" alt="Default product image" src="http://buytimg.dailyhunt.in/images/def_product.png">
            <h4>Title of Product</h4>
            <p>Product description</p>
            <h2 style="text-align: center">
                <span class="tag tag-success" style="width:100%">10 000$</span>
            </h2>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button">Add to Cart</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.border{
    border:1px solid grey;
}
.grey-border{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
.round-border{
    border-radius:10px;
}
.padding-top{
    padding-top:30px;
}
.padding-bottom{
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
.font-size-18{
    font-size:18pt;
}
```

Kind regards,
Michael